# ImportError: cannot import name '_png' from 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, kivy

I'm currently working with Python 3.7 on Pycharm and trying to get a better understanding of kivy. I found a script that I'm trying to run but I'm encountering an import error:
cannot import name '_png' from 'matplotlib'

Does anybody have any solution to this? Code below:

```
from matplotlib import use as mpl_use
mpl_use('module://kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivy')
```

Answer (score 0):

matplotlib version 3.1.0 did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently trying to key kivy to use bar charts from matplotlib in pycharm. If you could post your code that would be helpful. I am very new to this, so if you could explain how you use the 3.1 version too

Answer (score 0):

I have downgraded to 3.2.2 from 3.4.1 and it works for me!  Using the python 3.9.

Comment: You can tests downgrading to < 3.0.0 and see which one will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, and realized there were some incompatibilities with the imgaug version, so I downgraded from matplotlib version 3.5.2 to 3.4.2 and installed imgaug version 0.2.5.

Would advice you to check if you ran into some error msg while installing certain packages. And address them first and then follow up on the other errors.

Also ensure that the version downloaded is compatible with the other packages included in your project.

Code Used:

!pip uninstall matplotlib

!pip install matplotlib==3.4.2

!pip uninstall imgaug

!pip install imgaug==0.2.5